# failure due to bigendian on spark test

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

Following is the testsuit which is failing on spark.It is looking like specific to big-endian as it is passing on the little-endian system. Any inputs on these will be very useful.

testcase source code:

```
test("flatMapGroupsWithState - recovery from checkpoint uses state format version 1") {
    // Function to maintain the max event time as state and set the timeout timestamp based on the
    // current max event time seen. It returns the max event time in the state, or -1 if the state
    // was removed by timeout.
    val stateFunc = (key: String, values: Iterator[(String, Long)], state: GroupState[Long]) => {
      assertCanGetProcessingTime { state.getCurrentProcessingTimeMs() >= 0 }
      assertCanGetWatermark { state.getCurrentWatermarkMs() >= -1 }

      val timeoutDelaySec = 5
      if (state.hasTimedOut) {
        state.remove()
        Iterator((key, -1))
      } else {
        val valuesSeq = values.toSeq
        val maxEventTimeSec = math.max(valuesSeq.map(_._2).max, state.getOption.getOrElse(0L))
        val timeoutTimestampSec = maxEventTimeSec + timeoutDelaySec
        state.update(maxEventTimeSec)
        state.setTimeoutTimestamp(timeoutTimestampSec * 1000)
        Iterator((key, maxEventTimeSec.toInt))
      }
    }
    val inputData = MemoryStream[(String, Int)]
    val result =
      inputData.toDS
        .select($"_1".as("key"), $"_2".cast("timestamp").as("eventTime"))
        .withWatermark("eventTime", "10 seconds")
        .as[(String, Long)]
        .groupByKey(_._1)
        .flatMapGroupsWithState(Update, EventTimeTimeout)(stateFunc)

    val resourceUri = this.getClass.getResource(
      "/structured-streaming/checkpoint-version-2.3.1-flatMapGroupsWithState-state-format-1/").toURI

    val checkpointDir = Utils.createTempDir().getCanonicalFile
    // Copy the checkpoint to a temp dir to prevent changes to the original.
    // Not doing this will lead to the test passing on the first run, but fail subsequent runs.
    FileUtils.copyDirectory(new File(resourceUri), checkpointDir)

    inputData.addData(("a", 11), ("a", 13), ("a", 15))
    inputData.addData(("a", 4))

    testStream(result, Update)(
      StartStream(
        checkpointLocation = checkpointDir.getAbsolutePath,
        additionalConfs = Map(SQLConf.FLATMAPGROUPSWITHSTATE_STATE_FORMAT_VERSION.key -> "2")),
      /*
      Note: The checkpoint was generated using the following input in Spark version 2.3.1
      AddData(inputData, ("a", 11), ("a", 13), ("a", 15)),
      // Max event time = 15. Timeout timestamp for "a" = 15 + 5 = 20. Watermark = 15 - 10 = 5.
      CheckNewAnswer(("a", 15)),  // Output = max event time of a
      AddData(inputData, ("a", 4)),       // Add data older than watermark for "a"
      CheckNewAnswer(),                   // No output as data should get filtered by watermark
      */

      AddData(inputData, ("a", 10)),      // Add data newer than watermark for "a"
      CheckNewAnswer(("a", 15)),          // Max event time is still the same
      // Timeout timestamp for "a" is still 20 as max event time for "a" is still 15.
      // Watermark is still 5 as max event time for all data is still 15.

      Execute { query =>
        // Verify state format = 1
        val f = query.lastExecution.executedPlan.collect { case f: FlatMapGroupsWithStateExec => f }
        assert(f.size == 1)
        assert(f.head.stateFormatVersion == 1)
      },

      AddData(inputData, ("b", 31)),      // Add data newer than watermark for "b", not "a"
      // Watermark = 31 - 10 = 21, so "a" should be timed out as timeout timestamp for "a" is 20.
      CheckNewAnswer(("a", -1), ("b", 31))           // State for "a" should timeout and emit -1
    )
  }
```

failure is as follow:

```
[info]   == Results ==
[info]   !== Correct Answer - 1 ==   == Spark Answer - 1 ==
[info]    struct<_1:string,_2:int>   struct<_1:string,_2:int>
[info]   ![a,15]                     [a,10]
[info]
[info]
[info]   == Progress ==
[info]      StartStream(ProcessingTime(0),org.apache.spark.util.SystemClock@e140d1ac,Map(spark.sql.streaming.flatMapGroupsWithState.stateFormatVersion -> 2),/home/test/spark/target/tmp/spark-16dab6bf-9077-4bca-bbf4-4a3083438a5d)
[info]      AddData to MemoryStream[_1#2303,_2#2304]: (a,10)
[info]   => CheckNewAnswer: [a,15]
[info]      AssertOnQuery(<condition>, name)
[info]      AddData to MemoryStream[_1#2303,_2#2304]: (b,31)
[info]      CheckNewAnswer: [a,-1],[b,31]
[info]
[info]   == Stream ==
[info]   Output Mode: Update
[info]   Stream state: {MemoryStream[_1#2303,_2#2304]: 2}
[info]   Thread state: alive
[info]   Thread stack trace: java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
[info]   java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:943)
[info]   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1.apply$mcZ$sp(MicroBatchExecution.scala:215)
[info]   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProcessingTimeExecutor.execute(TriggerExecutor.scala:56)
[info]   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.runActivatedStream(MicroBatchExecution.scala:160)
[info]   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:281)
[info]   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:193)
[info]
[info]
[info]   == Sink ==
[info]   2: [a,10]
[info]
[info]
[info]   == Plan ==
[info]   == Parsed Logical Plan ==
[info]   SerializeFromObject [staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, assertnotnull(assertnotnull(input[0, scala.Tuple2, true]))._1, true, false) AS _1#2319, assertnotnull(assertnotnull(input[0, scala.Tuple2, true]))._2 AS _2#2320]
[info]   +- FlatMapGroupsWithState <function3>, cast(value#2314 as string).toString, newInstance(class scala.Tuple2), [value#2314], [key#2306, eventTime#2307-T10000ms], obj#2318: scala.Tuple2, class[value[0]: bigint], Update, false, EventTimeTimeout
[info]      +- AppendColumns <function1>, class scala.Tuple2, [StructField(_1,StringType,true), StructField(_2,LongType,false)], newInstance(class scala.Tuple2), [staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, input[0, java.lang.String, true], true, false) AS value#2314]
[info]         +- EventTimeWatermark eventTime#2307: timestamp, interval 10 seconds
[info]            +- Project [_1#2303 AS key#2306, cast(_2#2304 as timestamp) AS eventTime#2307]
[info]               +- Project [_1#2338 AS _1#2303, _2#2339 AS _2#2304]
[info]                  +- Streaming RelationV2 MemoryStreamDataSource$[_1#2338, _2#2339]
[info]
[info]   == Analyzed Logical Plan ==
[info]   _1: string, _2: int
[info]   SerializeFromObject [staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, assertnotnull(assertnotnull(input[0, scala.Tuple2, true]))._1, true, false) AS _1#2319, assertnotnull(assertnotnull(input[0, scala.Tuple2, true]))._2 AS _2#2320]
[info]   +- FlatMapGroupsWithState <function3>, cast(value#2314 as string).toString, newInstance(class scala.Tuple2), [value#2314], [key#2306, eventTime#2307-T10000ms], obj#2318: scala.Tuple2, class[value[0]: bigint], Update, false, EventTimeTimeout
[info]      +- AppendColumns <function1>, class scala.Tuple2, [StructField(_1,StringType,true), StructField(_2,LongType,false)], newInstance(class scala.Tuple2), [staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, input[0, java.lang.String, true], true, false) AS value#2314]
[info]         +- EventTimeWatermark eventTime#2307: timestamp, interval 10 seconds
[info]            +- Project [_1#2303 AS key#2306, cast(_2#2304 as timestamp) AS eventTime#2307]
[info]               +- Project [_1#2338 AS _1#2303, _2#2339 AS _2#2304]
[info]                  +- Streaming RelationV2 MemoryStreamDataSource$[_1#2338, _2#2339]
[info]
[info]   == Optimized Logical Plan ==
[info]   SerializeFromObject [staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, assertnotnull(input[0, scala.Tuple2, true])._1, true, false) AS _1#2319, assertnotnull(input[0, scala.Tuple2, true])._2 AS _2#2320]
[info]   +- FlatMapGroupsWithState <function3>, value#2314.toString, newInstance(class scala.Tuple2), [value#2314], [key#2306, eventTime#2307-T10000ms], obj#2318: scala.Tuple2, class[value[0]: bigint], Update, false, EventTimeTimeout
[info]      +- AppendColumns <function1>, class scala.Tuple2, [StructField(_1,StringType,true), StructField(_2,LongType,false)], newInstance(class scala.Tuple2), [staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, input[0, java.lang.String, true], true, false) AS value#2314]
[info]         +- EventTimeWatermark eventTime#2307: timestamp, interval 10 seconds
[info]            +- Project [_1#2338 AS key#2306, cast(_2#2339 as timestamp) AS eventTime#2307]
[info]               +- Streaming RelationV2 MemoryStreamDataSource$[_1#2338, _2#2339]
[info]
[info]   == Physical Plan ==
[info]   *(3) SerializeFromObject [staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, assertnotnull(input[0, scala.Tuple2, true])._1, true, false) AS _1#2319, assertnotnull(input[0, scala.Tuple2, true])._2 AS _2#2320]
[info]   +- FlatMapGroupsWithState <function3>, value#2314.toString, newInstance(class scala.Tuple2), [value#2314], [key#2306, eventTime#2307-T10000ms], obj#2318: scala.Tuple2, state info [ checkpoint = file:/home/test/spark/target/tmp/spark-16dab6bf-9077-4bca-bbf4-4a3083438a5d/state, runId = 9cc5efc0-97c5-48e6-89d5-66330069026a, opId = 0, ver = 2, numPartitions = 5], class[value[0]: bigint], 1, Update, EventTimeTimeout, 1575008112198, 5000
[info]      +- *(2) Sort [value#2314 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
[info]         +- Exchange hashpartitioning(value#2314, 5)
[info]            +- AppendColumns <function1>, newInstance(class scala.Tuple2), [staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, input[0, java.lang.String, true], true, false) AS value#2314]
[info]               +- EventTimeWatermark eventTime#2307: timestamp, interval 10 seconds
[info]                  +- *(1) Project [_1#2338 AS key#2306, cast(_2#2339 as timestamp) AS eventTime#2307]
[info]                     +- *(1) Project [_1#2338, _2#2339]
[info]                        +- *(1) ScanV2 MemoryStreamDataSource$[_1#2338, _2#2339] (StreamTest.scala:450)
[info]   org.scalatest.exceptions.TestFailedException:
[info]   at org.scalatest.Assertions$class.newAssertionFailedException(Assertions.scala:528)
[info]   at org.scalatest.FunSuite.newAssertionFailedException(FunSuite.scala:1560)
[info]   at org.scalatest.Assertions$class.fail(Assertions.scala:1089)
[info]   at org.scalatest.FunSuite.fail(FunSuite.scala:1560)
[info]   at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamTest$class.failTest$1(StreamTest.scala:450)
[info]   at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamTest$$anonfun$executeAction$1$20.apply(StreamTest.scala:751)
[info]   at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamTest$$anonfun$executeAction$1$20.apply(StreamTest.scala:751)
[info]   at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
[info]   at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamTest$class.executeAction$1(StreamTest.scala:750)
[info]   at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamTest$$anonfun$liftedTree1$1$1.apply(StreamTest.scala:770)
[info]   at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamTest$$anonfun$liftedTree1$1$1.apply(StreamTest.scala:757)
[info]   at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
[info]   at scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.foreach(WrappedArray.scala:35)
[info]   at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamTest$class.liftedTree1$1(StreamTest.scala:757)
[info]   at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamTest$class.testStream(StreamTest.scala:756)
[info]   at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.FlatMapGroupsWithStateSuite.testStream(FlatMapGroupsWithStateSuite.scala:48)
[info]   at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.FlatMapGroupsWithStateSuite$$anonfun$21.apply$mcV$sp(FlatMapGroupsWithStateSuite.scala:924)
[info]   at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.FlatMapGroupsWithStateSuite$$anonfun$21.apply(FlatMapGroupsWithStateSuite.scala:883)
[info]   at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.FlatMapGroupsWithStateSuite$$anonfun$21.apply(FlatMapGroupsWithStateSuite.scala:883)
[info]   at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf$class.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:85)
[info]   at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf$.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:104)
[info]   at org.scalatest.Transformer.apply(Transformer.scala:22)
[info]   at org.scalatest.Transformer.apply(Transformer.scala:20)
[info]   at org.scalatest.FunSuiteLike$$anon$1.apply(FunSuiteLike.scala:186)
[info]   at org.apache.spark.SparkFunSuite.withFixture(SparkFunSuite.scala:103)
[info]   at org.scalatest.FunSuiteLike$class.invokeWithFixture$1(FunSuiteLike.scala:183)
[info]   at org.scalatest.FunSuiteLike$$anonfun$runTest$1.apply(FunSuiteLike.scala:196)
[info]   at org.scalatest.FunSuiteLike$$anonfun$runTest$1.apply(FunSuiteLike.scala:196)
[info]   at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.runTestImpl(Engine.scala:289)
[info]   at org.scalatest.FunSuiteLike$class.runTest(FunSuiteLike.scala:196)
[info]   at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.FlatMapGroupsWithStateSuite.org$scalatest$BeforeAndAfterEach$$super$runTest(FlatMapGroupsWithStateSuite.scala:48)
[info]   at org.scalatest.BeforeAndAfterEach$class.runTest(BeforeAndAfterEach.scala:221)
[info]   at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.FlatMapGroupsWithStateSuite.runTest(FlatMapGroupsWithStateSuite.scala:48)
[info]   at org.scalatest.FunSuiteLike$$anonfun$runTests$1.apply(FunSuiteLike.scala:229)
[info]   at org.scalatest.FunSuiteLike$$anonfun$runTests$1.apply(FunSuiteLike.scala:229)
[info]   at org.scalatest.SuperEngine$$anonfun$traverseSubNodes$1$1.apply(Engine.scala:396)
[info]   at org.scalatest.SuperEngine$$anonfun$traverseSubNodes$1$1.apply(Engine.scala:384)
[info]   at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
[info]   at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.traverseSubNodes$1(Engine.scala:384)
[info]   at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.org$scalatest$SuperEngine$$runTestsInBranch(Engine.scala:379)
[info]   at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.runTestsImpl(Engine.scala:461)
[info]   at org.scalatest.FunSuiteLike$class.runTests(FunSuiteLike.scala:229)
[info]   at org.scalatest.FunSuite.runTests(FunSuite.scala:1560)
[info]   at org.scalatest.Suite$class.run(Suite.scala:1147)
[info]   at org.scalatest.FunSuite.org$scalatest$FunSuiteLike$$super$run(FunSuite.scala:1560)
[info]   at org.scalatest.FunSuiteLike$$anonfun$run$1.apply(FunSuiteLike.scala:233)
[info]   at org.scalatest.FunSuiteLike$$anonfun$run$1.apply(FunSuiteLike.scala:233)
[info]   at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.runImpl(Engine.scala:521)
[info]   at org.scalatest.FunSuiteLike$class.run(FunSuiteLike.scala:233)
[info]   at org.apache.spark.SparkFunSuite.org$scalatest$BeforeAndAfterAll$$super$run(SparkFunSuite.scala:52)
[info]   at org.scalatest.BeforeAndAfterAll$class.liftedTree1$1(BeforeAndAfterAll.scala:213)
[info]   at org.scalatest.BeforeAndAfterAll$class.run(BeforeAndAfterAll.scala:210)
[info]   at org.apache.spark.SparkFunSuite.run(SparkFunSuite.scala:52)
[info]   at org.scalatest.tools.Framework.org$scalatest$tools$Framework$$runSuite(Framework.scala:314)
[info]   at org.scalatest.tools.Framework$ScalaTestTask.execute(Framework.scala:480)
[info]   at sbt.ForkMain$Run$2.call(ForkMain.java:296)
[info]   at sbt.ForkMain$Run$2.call(ForkMain.java:286)
[info]   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[info]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
[info]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
[info]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:813)
```

Any information on what is happening here will be useful. It is passing on little-endian system. Issue looks specific to big-endian

Comment: Can you provide a way for us to reproduce your problem? Also, code is one thing but it would be very helpful if you could describe your problem with words.